# Setting protocols and load life cycle

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a set of protocols that I use on several of my UIViewControllers. Is there a way to set default code that runs on all of them when the protocol is set. Also is there a way to get them to work like the UIViewController life cycle, for example when a UIViewController loads it does?

```
 - (void)viewWillLoad;
 - (void(viewDidLoad;
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)anmated;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get code to run when a property is set (I assume that's what you meant?) you can just override the synthesised setter method

```
@synthesize value = _value;

- (void)setMyProperty:(id <MyProtocol>)value {
    if (value != value) {
        _value = value;

        // Insert your code here
        ...
    }
}
```

If you wanted all your view controllers to behave the same way they you could provide a common subclass of UIViewController i.e.

```
@interface AbstractViewController : UIViewController {
...
}
```

and then, all your 'real' view controllers would inherit from that, not directly from UIViewController :

```
@interface MainViewController : AbstractViewController { ... }

@interface DetailsViewController : AbstractViewController { ... }
```

If you added your property (and your overridden setter method) to the abstract view controller then all your real view controllers would get that functionality for free.

I hope that's helpful. If it's not, add more information to your question and we can try again :)

Comment: No that's great explains a lot.